# Storing Anaconda environment in alternate directory

Tags: python, bash, anaconda

Anaconda is installed on the machine I am using, but I exceed my disk quota when I create an environment. I have a large scratch space that I work in. Is there a way to store the environment in a different location than the /.conda/envs/ directory?

Comment: Move (mv) your `envs` directory somewhere else and create a symbolic link (ln -s) to its new position?

Comment: @Cyrus Thank you. That was easier than expected.